# Embedding CEF3 with existing application

Tags: chromium-embedded

I have a running WIN32 application. There a window in this application where I want to show web content using CEF3. But, I am facing problems and the entire window becomes white without showing any web page content. So I have the following questions:

1. Is it possible to use CEF3 with existing message loop in application? I dont want to call the CEF message loop, it may impact other things in my application.
2. Is it absolutely necessary to use a message window as in the sample application? I am not able to understand its objective.
3. When CEF3 launches multiple processes, how does it show in the task manager? If my application name is A.exe, does it show A.exe multiple times in task manager?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For windows users there is possible to use multi threaded message loop (CefSettings). It is allow maintain browser windows via own message loop. But there is good practice use single threaded message loop, - you can call CefDoMessageLoopWork periodiacally on idle or some additional events. It is possible even with existing message loop.
2. I'm not sure what you mean.
3. CefSettings.BrowserSubprocessPath specifies which executable will be used for child processes. While you are integrating it in other process, looks like it is one possible solution and in task manager you will see processes as you named it.

Answer (score 0):

About the question number 2:
every windows application has its own "main window" and wndProc that receives all the messages sent by his children. 
And the sample win32 cefclient shows how to integrate cef message loop inside the application's message loop.
And if you don't handle and dispatch cef messages in proper way the browser window becomes white.